# how to find out (programatically) when a program was last used using delphi

Tags: file, delphi

I would like to find out when a program was last used, using Delphi, and create a file from the information. The purpose is to get rid of all the programs that I have not used in the past year.

Comment: I believe Microsoft stopped even trying to track this because there's just no way to be absolutely sure. It's difficult to identify individual "programs" versus installed "software". Even if you had this information available, I certainly wouldn't trust it. Even IObit Uninstaller doesn't show you date last used - only date installed.

Comment: To add, I just checked. Yes, Windows has such a "feature", but as I guessed, it's far from accurate. Apparently, I haven't used my Delphi since May 4th 2017 (although I have it open right now).

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout That is correct, but how is that related to anything here?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout I haven't updated my profile here in I don't know how many years...